# How to replace a certain item in array C#

Tags: c#

I want to replace an certain element in an array, but the current method only replaces all elements.

For example, if I wanted to replace “q” with “w”:

```
public string example[] = {“q”, ”q”, “q”};
```

It would replace all “q”s with “w”s. I just want to replace only the third “q”. How would I do this?

Comment: Side note: please use straight quotes (`"`) instead of curly ones like you used in your question. Programming languages tend to not like curly quotes (and will error out). Regarding the question, why not just iterate over the indexes of the array, check if each element is a `"q"`, and if so, replace it with array indexing?

Comment: So do you want to replace EVERY third q that you find, or just the THIRD q?

Comment: The `Array.IndexOf` method lets you specify where to start searching. If you call it three times with appropriate starting indexes, you can find the third instance of a value. Now that you know what method to use, it's for you to work out the logic of using it.

Comment: Your code is not valid code… `public string example[] = {“q”, ”q”, “q”};` … is not valid… aside from the quotes as already noted, the bracket “[]” characters are invalid characters to be used in a variable name. Even if allowed, you have a “single” `string` and not an array of `strings`. I am guessing you want… `string[] example = {"q", "q", "q"};` … Then you could reference any single element in the array like… `example[2] = “w”;`

Comment: @LarryBud no just the third q

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your code is invalid.
should be as -depends to your C# version- :

```
var example = new []{"q", "q", "q"};
```

or

```
var example = new string[]{"q", "q", "q"};
```

or

```
string[] example = new string[]{"q", "q", "q"};
```

Anyway, let's turn back to your question.

To do something on specific items of a collection, you need to know some identifier (a unique specification for each item like idNo, indexNo etc.).

In your example, since it is a string array, there is no any other identifier than index no of the items.

So, you can simply edit specific items with

a-) Known index no `example[2] = "w"; // Editing 3rd item.`

and -if items of the collection are not the same-

b-) item itself  `example["q"] = "w";`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnG Thank you to warn me John. You're right. Editing now.

Comment: For whatever reason, it works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful extension method:

```cs
internal static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static int NthIndexOf<T>(this T[] source, T value, int n)
    {
        var index = -1;

        // Start the first search at the beginning of the array.
        var startIndex = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            index = Array.IndexOf(source, value, startIndex);

            // Start the next search at the index after the instance just found.
            startIndex = index + 1;

            if (index == -1 || startIndex == source.Length)
            {
                // The value was not found or we are at the end of the array.
                break;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```cs
var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(numbers.NthIndexOf(0, 0));
Console.WriteLine(numbers.NthIndexOf(0, 1));
Console.WriteLine(numbers.NthIndexOf(0, 2));
Console.WriteLine(numbers.NthIndexOf(0, 3));
Console.WriteLine(numbers.NthIndexOf(0, 4));
```

Output:

```
0
3
7
10
-1
```

That method will get the *n*th index of a value in an array, where `n` is zero-based. If you prefer it to be one-based then you can change `i <= n` to `i < n`. The code will return -1 if the specified value is not found or if there are fewer instances of that value than you requested.

Once you have the index of the element of interest, you set it like you would any other element of any other array.